# MS Project Macro VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-project

Writing a macro in MS Project that reads values from Excel. The macro should count the occurrence of a particular string in the Excel worksheet column. I use the following code:

```
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open("D:\VBA\Design\" + FileName + ".xls")
Set ObjWS = objWB.Worksheets(1)   

ObjWS.Activate

Dim lastRow As Integer   
lastRow = ObjWS.Range("A" & ObjWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Dim iVal As Double    
iVal = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ObjWS.Range("A1:A" & lastRow), "Resource:" & "*")
```

Problem: When I run the code for the first time I get

> Run time error 13 Type mismatch

where `iVal` is declared. But after stopping the execution and starting it again this error does not pop up.

Tried solutions: Changing the return type value to Integer, Long etc. But still the error persists.

Could anyone help me trace the issue and find a solution?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx) would suggest that your assignment before that (`lastRow = ObjWS.Range("A" & ObjWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`) could be the problem.

You declare `lastRow` as an Integer but the documentation states that `.Row` for a `Range` would be a read only long. This doesn't explain why it works the second time around but it might be the issue.

Comment: I tried the solution by changing lastRow to Long , but the problem still persists. I guess the problem lies in my close statement:

Comment: My close statement is:

Comment: objWB.Close savechanges:=False

Comment: Somehow when i run my code first the code works fine and the above statement is also executed . But when i run the code again( i find that an excel is still running in the 'task manager' window) the error pops up as type mismatch error 13. and the third time i run the same code i find the file is locked. How do i completely close or exit an excel file.

Comment: Please update the question with this additional information and add the actual close statement (and maybe the other code) as well. If your excel application is still running it would make sense to see an excel process in your task manager. As you're using a variable for the filename, are you opening one file or multiple files? How do you call it?